# Configure wlan0 interface at boot time

Tags: network-interface, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I've created with Yocto a Linux image for an IMX6 device.
I've modified the /etc/network/interface file in order to setup `usb0` and `wlan0`.

No problem with `usb0`, it's correctly setup at boot time. 
It does not work as expected for `wlan0`.

My `/etc/network/interface` looks like:

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0


auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The `wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like:

```
network={
    ssid="my_own_ssid"
    psk_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Having that done, if I tried:

```
ifup wlan0
```

I get:

```
udhcpc (v1.24.2) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
```

Same thing if I do:

```
/etc/init.d/S40network restart
```

However, I type the following command before:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext
ifup wlan0
```

It works.
I'm not a Linux expert, but I was understanding that wpa_supplicant was called by `/etc/network daemon`.

How can I do to have wlan0 setup at boot time ? Any suggestion is welcome.

Z.